# week number difference mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to filter some results of this week and next week. But it gives me no result for this week.

I have records with the date "2013-10-25 12:00:00" and "2013-10-22 12:00:00".

I am getting current week by `date('W', time())` in php and using `WEEK(tdi.due_at)` in mysql query.

`date('W', time())` return 43 which is current week number.

but `WEEK(tdi.due_at)` returns 42 why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL WEEK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) has also an optional mode parameter that sets the condition when the first week of a year starts.

Answer (score 0):

Why not you subtract -1 from PHP `date('W') - 1`.
or add +1 to MySQL `WEEK(tdi.due_at) + 1`.

PHP Indexed with 1 and MySQL starts index with 0 like JavaScript does.